# Closed 1-forms on Simply Connected Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Is it true that closed 1-forms on a simply connected differentiable manifold are exact. If so, could you explain why? Thanks very much

Comment: On a simply connected manifold, $H^1_{dR}(M) = 0$ and so all closed one form are exact. Or you can construct explicitly the function by $f(q) = \int_\gamma \alpha$, where $\gamma$ is any curve joining $p_0$ to $q$. (Simply connectedness imply that $f$ is well defined)>