# Every closed 1 form on a compact, simply connected manifold M is exact.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is simply connected, compact manifold.
Then I want to show that every closed $1-$ form is exact on $M$.

This is same showing that the first de-Rham cohomology space of $M$ is $0$.

**Question**: Is it possible to answer this without using universal coefficients theorem?

(The reason for not using the universal coefficients theorem is that it contains a mystery term ext which I'm not comfortable using. Digging deeper into ext, it turns out that it is a core algebraic term which I'm not good enough at at this stage.)

Since $M$ is simply connected, its fundamental group $\pi_1$ is $0$.
First homology group $H_1$ is abeliazation of $\pi_1$ so $H_1 =0$.
To conclude $H^1=0$, I would need universal coefficients theorem, which is what I want to avoid.

Does the following work?

Suppose that $\omega$ is a closed $1$ form on $M$. Consider any $p$ in M. Take a chart at $p$ and call it $h$. Then $\tau=(h^{-1})^\ast \omega$ is a $1$ form on $\mathbb R^n$ hence equal to $df$ for some smooth $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$.
Pulling $\tau$ back to $M$ and using that fact that $d$ and $\ast$ commute, I have $\omega= d(h^\ast f)$. This is true for every point $p$. Locally this is fine.

But here $h$ is not the same function throughout. $h$ depends upon $p$. So how to create a $0$ form $g$ on $M$ such that $\omega =dg$?

Comment: I suppose in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154074/closed-1-forms-on-simply-connected-manifold#:~:text=On%20a%20simply%20connected%20manifold,that%20f%20is%20well%20definedd) comment section your question gets answered.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar: I didn't want to define $g$ that way because I don't know how to integrate a form on a curve. I know how to integrate a form on a manifold.

Comment: But a curve is a $1$-manifold?

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar: So if $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ is a smooth map, then image ($\gamma)$ is a $1-$ manifold?

Comment: Yes, in this case $\gamma$ is you parametrization, so $\int_\gamma \omega = \int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* \omega$.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar: I think that the curve may not be a 1 manifold because what if the curve is constant?

Comment: Nonetheless, I think that you are right in that $\int_{\gamma} \omega= \int_{[a,b]}\gamma^\ast \omega$ but I don't know why this is true exactly. I suppose this is a definition for 'integrating a form on curves' but I haven't seen it before. Could you please direct me to where I can see this definition? If this is settled, then my question is also partly answered because then I can define g using $\gamma$.

Comment: I was just about to comment about this, since I thought it was unclear, but of course you need $\gamma$ to be an immersion, so that the image is a manifold. This means in the case of a curve, the rank of the derivate of $\gamma$ has to be 1 for every point $p \in [a,b]$

Comment: This is the general definition for integration of k-forms on a manifold, which is covered by one chart. You can look it up in Lee‘s Smooth Manifolds, the line integral is a special case of it, if you simply it further you will get to the definition of a line integral like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral). I forgot to mention in my previous comment, but $\gamma$ has to be open too, or rather be an embedding.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar: I didn't find the definition in Lee's book. It's not there is Tu's book either.

Comment: Lee's Smooth Manifolds $2$nd ed. p.$404$ $(16.1)$

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar I looked at that. But that definition is not for integration of a form on a curve. That definition is for the case when M is covered by a single chart $\phi$.

Comment: Since this question is not directly related to the post, I felt I should post a separate question on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4890626/source-of-the-definition-of-integrating-a-form-along-a-curve-in-a-manifold

Comment: Yes and curve which is a $1$-Manifold, is essentially covered by one $\phi$, because for the curve to be a 1- manifold M $\gamma: [a,b]  \longrightarrow M=im(\gamma)$ has to be an embedding. So $\phi=\gamma^{-1}$ is our chart which covers M.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar: But $\gamma$ doesn't have to an embedding for the definition to make sense, right? The definition seems to make sense for any smooth gamma but I don't know why. I understand the case when \gamma is an embedding and immersion.

Comment: Maybe p.$289$ is helpful, for you.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar It does. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your **Question**, note that one does not need universal coefficients to state at least some link between $\newcommand{\HdR}{H_\mathrm{dR}}\HdR^1(M)$ and $\pi_1(M)$. Namely, you can define a map $\Phi\colon \HdR^1(M) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathrm{Grp}}(\pi_1(M, x), \mathbb{R})$ (where $x \in M$ is any point) via
$$
    \Phi([\omega])([\gamma]) = \int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \omega
$$
where $\tilde{\gamma} \in [\gamma]$ is a smooth representative (here the integral is the usual line integral, i.e. it is given by $\int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \omega = \int_{[a, b]} \tilde{\gamma}^* \omega$ for $\tilde{\gamma}\colon [a, b] \to M$ a smooth curve). It turns out that this map is an isomorphism, and you can at least see directly that it is injective without resorting to de Rham's theorem and singular cohomology at all: In fact, if $\int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \omega = 0$ for all choices of $\tilde{\gamma}$, then it is not hard to see that $\int_\sigma \omega = 0$ for $\sigma$ a  smooth closed curve based at another point $y \in M$, whence $\omega$ is conservative and therefore $[\omega] = 0$ (for some more details, see Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Theorem 17.17). Obviously, then, if $\pi_1(M, x) = 0$, so, too, must be $\HdR^1(M)$.

...but of course, you don't really need to invoke the universal coefficient theorem to go from $H_1(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ to $H^1(M; \mathbb{R}) \cong \HdR^1(M) = 0$ either! Namely, let $(C_\bullet(M), d_\bullet) = (\cdots \overset{d_2}{\to} C_1(M) \overset{d_1}{\to} C_0(M))$ be the singular chain complex of $M$ computing $H_\bullet(M; \mathbb{Z})$. Note that $H_1(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ is the same as saying that this complex is *exact* at $C_1(M)$, i.e. that $\operatorname{img} d_2 = \ker d_1$. To go from this to the cochain complex defining $H^\bullet(M; \mathbb{R})$, you by definition apply $\operatorname{Hom}({{-}}, \mathbb{R})$ to get
$$
    \operatorname{Hom}(C_0(M), \mathbb{R}) \overset{d_1^*}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Hom}(C_1(M), \mathbb{R}) \overset{d_2^*}{\longrightarrow} \cdots 
$$
and take its cohomology, but since $\mathbb{R}$ is injective, $\operatorname{Hom}({{-}}, \mathbb{R})$ is exact, which implies that $\operatorname{img} d_1^* = \ker d_2^*$, whence $H^1(M; \mathbb{R}) = 0$.

As for the question about explicitly finding a 0-form whose derivative is any given 1-form, I'll gladly leave it to somebody else :)