# Source of the definition of integrating a form along a curve in a manifold

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth manifold. Let $\omega$ be an $n-$ form on $M$ with compact support. Then we define $\int_M\omega$ using partitions of unity. If $M$ is covered by a single chart $h:M\to \mathbb R^n$, then we define $\int_M\omega:= \int_{\mathbb R^n} (h^{-1})^\ast \omega$, where $\ast$ denotes pullback. $\tag 1$

But often the following definition is stated:

$\int_{\gamma} \omega := \int_{[0,1]} \gamma^\ast \omega$, where $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ is a smooth curve and $\omega$ is a $1$- form on $M$. $\tag 2$

My questions are:

$(a)$ what is the source of the definition in $(2)$?

$(b)$ Does this somehow follow from the definition in $(1)$?

I think the answer to $(b)$ is no because taking the definition in $(1)$ to be a general definition, the term $\int_{\gamma} \omega$ makes sense iff $\gamma[0,1]$ is a $1$- manifold but that's not the case in general: Smooth image of a $1$- manifold is not necessarily a manifold.

That brings me back to $(a)$. I didn't find the definition $(2)$ neither in Tu's book nor in Lee's book nor in Spivak's.

Can anyone please direct me to where the definition $(2)$ has been stated?

Comment: If your curve isn’t closed then you’ll need a notion of integrating along a manifold with boundary.

Comment: Do you know about integration on chains?

Comment: First, note that the definition in the first paragraph holds for $n=1$. Second, note that $\gamma^*\omega$ is a $1$-form on the $1$-dimensional manifold $[0,1]$. Therefore, the definition in the first paragraph can be used to define $$\int_\gamma\omega$$.

Answer (score 5):

This notion is known as a "line integral" and you should have already encountered it in the special case that $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ in a lecture on analysis. Lee has an entire chapter on this concept, this exact definition is stated on p.289 (in the Second Edition). For the other question, yes, integrating over $[0,1]$ is a special case of your definition $(1)$ (as long as you modify it to allow $M$ to have boundary, which is something Lee does). The notation $\int_{\gamma}\omega$ is just that, a notation. It is not meant to imply that the image of the curve is a submanifold to be integrated over (and in the case that the curve *is* embedded, those interpretations would agree).